# How do I "bind" social networks account to my blog?

Tags: seo, wordpress, social-media

My girlfriend has a WordPress blog for a while now, but when we check tools like websiteworth or woorank, it tells us that she has no twitter or G+ account, which is false.

Is there a way to "bind" her social network accounts with her blog ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as binding social networks to a website. Basically, if those tools (whose values is debatable. I think they're worthless) don't work, they don't work. Contact the tool owner and let them know their tools shortcomings and maybe they'll fix it.

Comment: I agree with John. Most of these so-called tools are really just scraping data from Alexa which is terrible/horrible/pathetic/miserable/God awful(!) to begin with. Seriously. Stop looking at them!